# convert txt column data (string) to int using python 2.7(by np.array.astype function)

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
f=open('00001.txt','r')

if f==0:
    print("fail to open the file")
else:
    print("file successfully opened")
    data=f.readlines()
    a = np.array(data)  
    yvec1 = a.astype(int)
    print(yvec1)
if f.close()==0:
    print("fail to close file")
else:
    print("file closed")
```

and this is the answer:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Original text data is:

```
name
716
722
729
732
730
728
729
733
735
737
737
739
741
744
747
749
747
742
742
742
742
741
739
738
736
734
732
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it this way since it is more "pythonic":

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Read your file properly
with open('00001.txt', 'r') as f
    # Retrieve the data without '\n' code (it was your problem)
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    # Load it in numpy
    a = np.array(data)
    # Do what you want with it
    yvec1 = a.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `a = np.array(data.split('\n'))` - the problem is that when you read file that way each line contains new-line symbol `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because /n cannot be converted to int as it is not a numerical character.

Try this:

```
data=f.readlines()
data_int = []
for item in data:
  data_int.append(int(item))
a = np.array(data_int)  
yvec1 = a.astype(int)
print(yvec1)
```

Comment: Do you know `data` is a list and you are calling `int()` on a list?